# How to instrument Java application code metrics to Prometheus

Tags: java, prometheus

I am trying to export customized values metrics of my Java application to Prometheus. I have read that it could be done with Push Gateway, following an example I use the next method:

```
static void executeBatchJob() throws Exception {
     CollectorRegistry registry = new CollectorRegistry();
     Gauge duration = Gauge.build()
         .name("my_batch_job_duration_seconds").help("Duration of my batch job in seconds.").register(registry);
     Gauge.Timer durationTimer = duration.startTimer();
     try {
       // Your code here.
       myCode();
       // This is only added to the registry after success,
       // so that a previous success in the Pushgateway isn't overwritten on failure.
       Gauge lastSuccess = Gauge.build()
           .name("my_batch_job_last_success").help("Last time my batch job succeeded, in unixtime.").register(registry);
       lastSuccess.setToCurrentTime();
     } finally {
       durationTimer.setDuration();
       PushGateway pg = new PushGateway("172.16.124.40:9091");
       pg.pushAdd(registry, "my_batch_job");
     }
   }
```

But when I run the project I am having the next error: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/prometheus/client/exporter/common/TextFormat
    at io.prometheus.client.exporter.PushGateway.doRequest(PushGateway.java:299)
    at io.prometheus.client.exporter.PushGateway.pushAdd(PushGateway.java:158)
    at nemshelloworld.NemsHelloWorld.executeBatchJob2(NemsHelloWorld.java:78)
    at nemshelloworld.NemsHelloWorld.main(NemsHelloWorld.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)`

Comment: You should use the exporter, not the push gateway. You also might want to consider micrometer.io facade

Comment: @Marged I use the exporter, but only exports JVM default metrics, I would like to export customized metrics inside the Java code. Micrometer is not used for spring? Can I use to in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `simpleclient_common` module, which is a listed dependency of `simpleclient_pushgateway` so it sounds like your pom.xml or equivalent isn't right.

Comment: Thanks! I add the simpleclient_common and it works perfect library